# Form Helper not found when using select_recurring for Ice_Cube with Formtastic and ActiveAdmin.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic, ice-cube

When using the [`select_recurring`](https://github.com/GetJobber/recurring_select) form helper for the [Ice_Cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) gem in Formtastic with ActiveAdmin I receive a `unable to find input class for select_recurring` error.

```
  form do |f|
    #Debugging
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
      f.input :description,  :hint => "Full description for the event"
      f.input :short_description, :hint => "Shot description for the event that will be displayed as a thumbnail"
      f.input :published
      f.input :event_date
      f.input :recurring_rule, :as => :select_recurring
    end

    f.actions
  end
```

Accessing it directly (below) works for the recurring schedule element but breaks all of the rest of the formtastic `f.input` elements.

```
f.select_recurring :recurring_schedule
```

How can I incorporate `select_recurring` into ActiveAdmin?

Comment: you answered your own question here: https://github.com/GetJobber/recurring_select/issues/55
can you add this an answer so that it can be upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worked for me (AA 1.0.0.pre1)

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
  #...
    li do
      f.label :recurring_rule_column
      f.select_recurring :recurring_rule_column, nil, :allow_blank => true
    end
  #...
  end
  f.submit
end
```